# Convert an int to byte in java

Tags: java, byte

```
String boxVal = "FB";
Integer val = Integer.parseInt(boxVal, 16);
System.out.println(val); //prints out 251
byte sboxValue = (byte) val;
System.out.println("sboxValue = " + Integer.toHexString(sboxValue)); //fffffffb
```

The last line should print out "fb". I am not sure why it prints out "fffffffb."
What am I doing wrong? How should I fix my code to print "fb"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why does it print "fffffffb": because you first convert the byte value (which is -5) to an integer with value -5 and then print that integer.

The easiest way to get the output you want is:

```
System.out.printf("sboxValue = %02x\n", sboxValue);
```

Or, you could also use:

```
System.out.println("sboxValue = " + Integer.toHexString(sboxValue & 0xff));
```

What happens here in detail:

the byte value `fb` is converted to an integer. Since the value is negative, as you can see because the leftmost bit is 1, it is sign extended to 32 bits: `fffffffb`.

By masking out the lower 8 bits (with the bitwise and operation &) we get the integer value `000000fb`.

Comment: Thank you. But I am not converting any byte value to an integer.

Comment: @Nayana you do, the `Integer.toHexString` method takes an integer as argument.

Comment: Not just for printing out, what if I wanted to use that byte value, which is sboxvalue? for example, as a string?

Comment: A byte in Java is a signed quantity and can hold values from -128 to 127. The bit pattern `fb` corresponds to the value -5 (= 251 - 256). This is the so called two's complement representation of negative integers.

Comment: Wow. That fixed the error. Thank you so much. But I still don't quite understand. Could you explain what you mean by -5 and the logic behind sboxValue & 0xff?

Comment: I see. So, by doing sboxValue & 0xff, it simply adds 255 to -5? But then, it becomes 250 (!= 251). Also, I shouldn't do & 0xff to numbers in the byte range, right? That'd cause errors too?

Comment: It does not add 255, it clears the upper 24 bits. & is a bitwise operation. If you work it out, you see that values from 0 to 127 are not changed and values from -128 to -1 become 128 to 255. So the net effect is to convert a signed byte value to an unsigned one.

Comment: Ah! I get it now. I did some google search. Apparently my brain's forgotten everything I learned in entry-level cs courses. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You have an overflow when you convert 251 to a byte. Byte has a minimum value of -128 and a maximum value of 127 (inclusive)

See here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html